# Ошибка в условии: E2027 Must take address of a memory location

Tags: c++

```
//проверка столбцов с одинаковым произведением
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 if (P[i]=min) & (i!=nomerstolbca) {
 if (flag2) {
  cout<<"Nomera stolbcov s odinakovymy proizvedenyami " << nomerstolbca << " , ";
 flag2=0;
 }
 cout<<i+1;
  }
}
```

выдаёт ошибку:  E2027 Must take address of a memory location в этом месте: (i!=nomerstolbca). Курсор стоит между ! и =. Никак не пойму в чём дело

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во второй строке вместо `&` напишите `&&`

P.S. Вообще строка должна так выглядеть

```
if ((P[i]==min) && (i!=nomerstolbca)) {
```

Comment: Написал так:  if (P[i]=min) && (i!=nomerstolbca)и теперь вылетает такая ошибка: [BCC32 Error] File1.cpp(48): E2188 Expression syntax

Comment: Спасибо помогло)

Comment: А теперь проанализируй свои ошибки.

Comment: @Никола Кривошея, обратите внимание, что мировой запас скобок неограничен.

Так что, если сомневаетесь в приоритете операций, не бойтесь их расставлять.

Comment: @avp, золотые слова

Comment: каждая лишняя скобка увеличивает время компиляции (хоть и немножко). А это ведет к выделению дополнительного тепла и к глобальному потеплению:))) (для тех кто в танке: это юмор)

Comment: @KoVadim с другой стороны, если открывающая скобка ведет к выделению тепла, то закрывающая должна приводить к его поглощению, то есть угроза глобального потепления несколько преувеличена)))

Comment: они складываются по модулю!

Comment: если бы это было та, то тогда две открывающие скобки должны были аннигилировать